# Save allure report in PDF and email

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, allure

I have setup allure reporting system with testng using Maven. My boss wants reports in emailable format or PDF format. Is there any why to save allure report in pdf?

Comment: not yet, but we are going to implement such feature soon https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/273

Comment: @DmitryBaev: Any idea till when this will be completed?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, Allure reports are not a standalone / HTML Reports. the reports should be hosted in webserver. But if your using jenkins for Test Executions with Allure Plugin in Jenkins will take care of this with build wise executions and then u export that to PDF.